# Why in this code a rectangle doesn't move when its coordinates are changed?

Tags: animation, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I recently started learning assembly (TASM) and I'm currently learning how to properly change the positions of different shapes.

I have the following code:

```
.model small
 
.stack 100h
 
.data

    ; codes returned int 16h ah = 00h
    ; the arrows we control 
        kbArrowUp       equ     4800h
        kbArrowDown     equ     5000h
        kbArrowLeft     equ     4B00h
        kbArrowRight    equ     4D00h
        kbEsc           equ     011Bh
        
        ; color codes of symbols and points in graphic mode
        Red             equ     4
        Gray            equ     7
        Blue            equ     1
        White           equ     15
 
        Mode0D_W        equ     320     ; screen width in pixels for video mode 0Dh
        Mode0D_H        equ     200     ; screen height in pixels for video mode 0Dh
        Mode0D_C        equ     16      ; number of colors for video mode 0Dh
        Mode0D_A        equ     0A000h  ; starting address of video memory for video mode 0Dh
 
        VideoPage       db      ?       ;video page number
 
        Xstart          dw      100     ; coordinates of the beginning of the square
        Ystart          dw      70

 
        sqColor         dw      1       ; color of the rendered rectangle
        sqWidth         dw      40      ; rectangle width
        sqHeight        dw      40      ; height of the rectangle


        XstartS          dw      150     ;coordinates of the beginning of the square
        YstartS          dw      70
 
        sqColorS         dw      1       ;color of the rendered rectangle
        sqWidthS         dw      15      ;rectangle width
        sqHeightS        dw      80      ;height of the rectangle
 

; macro to simplify calling procedures with parameters
    invoke  macro   CallProc, Params
            IRP     P, <Params>
                    mov     ax,     P
                    push    ax
            endm
            call    CallProc
    endm
 
.code
 
main    proc
        mov     ax,     @data
        mov     ds,     ax
 
       
       ; setting graphics video mode
        mov     ax,     000Dh
        int     10h
 
        mov     ah,     0Fh     ; clarification of video mode parameters
        int     10h
        mov     [VideoPage],    bh
 
        invoke  Bar, <[sqHeight], [sqWidth], [Ystart], [Xstart], [sqColor] >
 
        @@GetCmd:
               ; waiting for any key
                mov     ah,     00h
                int     16h
                ;обработка команды
        @@TestCmd1:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowUp
                jne     @@TestCmd2
                mov     dx,     [Ystart]
                cmp     dx,     0
                je      @@GetCmd
                dec     dx
                mov     cx,     [Xstart]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd2:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowDown
                jne     @@TestCmd3
                mov     dx,     [Ystart]
                add     dx,     [sqWidth]
                cmp     dx,     Mode0D_H
                jae     @@GetCmd
                mov     dx,     [Ystart]
                inc     dx
                mov     cx,     [Xstart]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd3:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowLeft
                jne     @@TestCmd4
                mov     cx,     [Xstart]
                cmp     cx,     0
                je      @@GetCmd
                dec     cx
                mov     dx,     [Ystart]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd4:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowRight
                jne     @@TestCmd5
                mov     cx,     [Xstart]
                add     cx,     [sqWidth]
                cmp     cx,     Mode0D_W
                jae     @@GetCmd
                mov     cx,     [Xstart]
                inc     cx
                mov     dx,     [Ystart]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd5:
                cmp     ax,     kbEsc
                jne     @@TestCmd1S
                jae     @@GetCmdS

        invoke  Bar, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], [YstartS], [XstartS], [sqColorS] >
        @@GetCmdS:
                ;ожидание нажатия любой клавиши
                mov     ah,     00h
                int     16h
                ;обработка команды
        @@TestCmd1S:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowUp
                jne     @@TestCmd2S
                mov     dx,     [YstartS]
                cmp     dx,     0
                jae      @@GetCmdS
                dec     dx
                mov     cx,     [XstartS]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd2S:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowDown
                jne     @@TestCmd3S
                mov     dx,     [YstartS]
                add     dx,     [sqWidthS]
                cmp     dx,     Mode0D_H
                jae     @@GetCmdS
                mov     dx,     [YstartS]
                inc     dx
                mov     cx,     [XstartS]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd3S:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowLeft
                jne     @@TestCmd4S
                mov     cx,     [XstartS]
                cmp     cx,     0
                je      @@GetCmdS
                dec     cx
                mov     dx,     [YstartS]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd4S:
                cmp     ax,     kbArrowRight
                jne     @@TestCmd5S
                mov     cx,     [XstartS]
                add     cx,     [sqWidthS]
                cmp     cx,     Mode0D_W
                jae     @@GetCmdS
                mov     cx,     [XstartS]
                inc     cx
                mov     dx,     [YstartS]
                jmp     @@Redraw
        @@TestCmd5S:
                cmp     ax,     kbEsc
                jne     @@GetCmdS
                jmp     @@StopCmdLoop
        @@Redraw:
                invoke  Bar, <[sqHeight], [sqWidth], [Ystart], [Xstart], 0>
                mov     ax,     [sqColor]
                inc     ax                      ;Color++
                cmp     ax,     Mode0D_C        ;if (Color>MaxColor)
                sbb     bx,     bx              ;  Color=1
                and     ax,     bx
                cmp     ax,     1
                adc     ax,     0
                mov     [sqColor],      ax
                mov     [Xstart],       cx
                mov     [Ystart],       dx
                invoke  Bar, <[sqHeight], [sqWidth], dx, cx, [sqColor]>
        jmp     @@GetCmd
        @@RedrawS:
                invoke  BarS, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], [YstartS], [XstartS], 0>
                mov     ax,     [sqColorS]
                inc     ax                      ;Color++
                cmp     ax,     Mode0D_C        ;if (Color>MaxColor)
                sbb     bx,     bx              ;  Color=1
                and     ax,     bx
                cmp     ax,     1
                adc     ax,     0
                mov     [sqColorS],      ax
                mov     [XstartS],       cx
                mov     [YstartS],       dx
                invoke  BarS, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], dx, cx, [sqColor]>
        jmp     @@GetCmdS
@@StopCmdLoop:
        ;переключение в текстовый режим
        mov     ax,     0003h
        int     10h
        ;завершение программы
        mov     ax,     4C00h
        int     21h
main    endp
 
;рисование полосы (залитого прямоугольника)
;на входе:
; color - цвет заливки
; x_pos, y_pos - координаты левого верхнего угла
; x_size, y_size - размеры прямоугольника
;на выходе:
; -
Bar     proc    color: word, x_pos:word, y_pos: word, x_size: word, y_size: word
        push    bp                      ;формирование кадра параметров
        mov     bp,     sp
 
        push    ax                      ;сохранение регистров
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    si
        push    di
 
        mov     ah,     0Ch             ; настройка параметров для вызова функции 0Ch
        mov     al,     byte ptr color           ;цвет точек
        mov     bh,     0               ;номер видеостраницы
        mov     dx,     y_pos           ;строка
        mov     cx,     x_pos           ;колонка
 
        mov     di,     y_size
@@Vertical:
 
        mov     cx,     x_pos           ;колонка
        mov     si,     x_size          ;вывести x_size точек в горизонтальной линии
@@Horizontal:
        int     10h                     ;вывести точку
        inc     cx                      ;прирастить координату x
        dec     si
        jnz     @@Horizontal
 
        inc     dx                      ;переход к следующей горизонтальной линии с
        dec     di
        jnz     @@Vertical
 
        pop     di                      ;восстановление рагистров
        pop     si
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
 
        pop     bp
        ret     10                      ;удаление параметров из стека
Bar     endp

BarS     proc    colorS: word, x_posS:word, y_posS: word, x_sizeS: word, y_sizeS: word
        push    bp                      ;формирование кадра параметров
        mov     bp,     sp
 
        push    ax                      ;сохранение регистров
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    si
        push    di
 
        mov     ah,     0Ch             ; настройка параметров для вызова функции 0Ch
        mov     al,     byte ptr colorS           ;цвет точек
        mov     bh,     0               ;номер видеостраницы
        mov     dx,     y_posS           ;строка
        mov     cx,     x_posS          ;колонка
 
        mov     di,     y_sizeS
@@VerticalS:
 
        mov     cx,     x_posS           ;колонка
        mov     si,     x_sizeS         ;вывести x_size точек в горизонтальной линии
@@HorizontalS:
        int     10h                     ;вывести точку
        inc     cx                      ;прирастить координату x
        dec     si
        jnz     @@Horizontal
 
        inc     dx                      ;переход к следующей горизонтальной линии с
        dec     di
        jnz     @@Vertical
 
        pop     di                      ;восстановление рагистров
        pop     si
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
 
        pop     bp
        ret     10                      ;удаление параметров из стека
BarS     endp
 
end     main
```

There's one thing I don't understand:
When I change the coordinates of the rectangle (*XstartS* and *YstartS*), the rectangle's position does not change.

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOuJc.jpg)

I want the rectangle to be centered and under the square, like this:

[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t8im.jpg)

Could you explain me a couple of things:

1. Why in this code a rectangle doesn't move when its coordinates are changed?
2. What should correct code look like, so that the result is displayed as in the second screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your program is never drawing the second shape!

What you see on the screen is an irregular redrawing of the first shape due to a number of errors that I have listed below:

> ```
> @@TestCmd2:
>     cmp     ax,     kbArrowDown
>     jne     @@TestCmd3
>     mov     dx,     [Ystart]
>     add     dx,     [sqWidth]
> ```

Here you need to add the height `[sqHeight]` instead of the width `[sqWidth]`.
Because for the 1st shape *width* equals *height* (it's a square after all), you don't see this error reflected on the screen. **But,** you made the same error for the 2nd shape where the width is different from the height, and *that* you will see once the 2nd shape finally gets drawn.

---

> ```
> @@TestCmd5:
>     cmp     ax,     kbEsc    (*)
>     jne     @@TestCmd1S      (*)
>     jae     @@GetCmdS        (*)
>
>     invoke  Bar, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], [YstartS], [XstartS], [sqColorS] >
> @@GetCmdS:
>     mov     ah,     00h
>     int     16h
> @@TestCmd1S:
> ```

The 2nd bar is never drawn here! If the key is not <kbd>ESC</kbd> then you jump to *TestCmd1S* and if the key is <kbd>ESC</kbd> you jump to *GetCmdS*. The `invoke Bar ...` cannot execute.

I have followed your program flow and as it turns out you don't need to test for <kbd>ESC</kbd> here at all. You can simply remove the 3 instructions that I've marked with an asterisk (*).

---

> ```
> @@TestCmd1S:
>     cmp     ax,     kbArrowUp
>     jne     @@TestCmd2S
>     mov     dx,     [YstartS]
>     cmp     dx,     0
>     jae      @@GetCmdS
> ```

The conditional jump `jae` here acts like an unconditional jump because of the 'above' condition being always true with the numbers in use! You need the `je` instruction here.

---

Your program contains 8 `jmp @@Redraw` instructions and not a single `jmp @@RedrawS`!
The top part needs 4 `jmp @@Redraw` instructions and the bottom part needs 4 `jmp @@RedrawS` instructions.

---

> ```
> invoke  BarS, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], dx, cx, [sqColor]>
> ```

The color is in `[sqColorS]` for the 2nd shape.

---

I'm confident that once the above errors are corrected the program will work as intended (moving rectangles).

---

[**Late catch**]
You don't need 2 identical procedures *Bar* and *BarS* in your program!

Instead of

```
invoke  Bar, <[sqHeight], [sqWidth], dx, cx, [sqColor]>
invoke  BarS, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], dx, cx, [sqColorS]>
```

you can safely use

```
invoke  Bar, <[sqHeight], [sqWidth], dx, cx, [sqColor]>
invoke  Bar, <[sqHeightS], [sqWidthS], dx, cx, [sqColorS]>
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, but the code still does not work as I need it (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mb_ivvWwbH9t2IaSurRC8rIAG99EnDqk/view?usp=sharing) I would be very grateful if you would correct my mistakes in the document

Comment: @EmelianenkoMikhail Debugging external code is not what this forum is about. If you have any question(s) about a program then you need to post its code on this here forum. I was under the impression that your current post already contained the whole program. If, with corrections, the current code does not work, then explain in detail what is missing...